# ToolTip on a Control WPF

Tags: wpf, location, tooltip

I want to show `ToolTip` on a Control (for example on a `TextBox`) when I click on a button. I use these codes:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip t = new System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip();
    t.Content = "Hello";
    t.PlacementTarget = txtCannyT1;
    t.IsOpen = true;
    t.StaysOpen = false;
}
```

But `ToolTip` is rised around mouse pointer. How can I set the location on `txtCannyT1` (which is `TextBox` instance)?

I need to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that you cannot set `t.StaysOpen = false;` because it raises the following exception:

> By default, ToolTip property does not support ToolTip element with StaysOpen set to false

You can use

```
t.Placement = PlacementMode.Top;
t.Placement = PlacementMode.Bottom;
t.Placement = PlacementMode.Center;
```

or similar options.

You can also set

```
t.Placement = PlacementMode.Relative;
```

with a combination of `t.VerticalOffset` or `t.HorizontalOffset` too.

Comment: This answer is complete, even it answers my next question. TNX

Answer (score 1):

In WPF, you normally specify a ToolTip by setting the ToolTip property of the UI element; you can do this in the XAML or [programmatically](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tooltip(v=vs.110).aspx).  You do not create the ToolTip control manually yourself.

```
_element.ToolTip = "This is the tooltip";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Tooltip.Show("Hello", txtCannyT1, x, y);
```

This will allow you to specify the location where the tooltip is displayed.

Comment: I think you've put a WinForms answer on a WPF question... WPF ToolTip class doesn't have a `Show` method.